# Quickly remove all files from a git repository

Tags: git

In a repository I have there are lots of unnecessary files, which I would like to remove from the repo and only keep locally. I understand that this is done by:

```
git rm --cached a_file
```

... or with `-r` in case it's a folder.

Now, it's easier to remove everything and add the few files I need.
If I use `*`, git rightly complains when it's given files that are not in the repo, but in the same local folder.

How should I proceed?

EDIT:
Using the `-f` flag won't work either:

```
$ git rm --cached -fr *
fatal: pathspec 'somefile' did not match any files
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `-f` flag? No idea if that would work in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--ignore-unmatch` flag for `git rm` does exactly what you want from what I can tell.

```
$ git rm --cached bla
fatal: pathspec 'bla' did not match any files
$ git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch bla
$
```